# Django how to make this query more efficient

Tags: python, django, orm

I have two models:

```python
class Answer(models.Model):
    ...

class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    answer_id = models.Foreignkey(Answer, related_name='photos')
```

The relationship is one-to-many (one answer has many photos)

I need to write a reporting function that outputs all answers along with corresponding photos. Here is what I have:

```python
def report():
    answers = Answer.objects.all()

    for answer in answers:
        result = extract_data(answer)
        for photo in answer.photos.all(): # <- executed N times, as N = # of answers in db
            result += photo.name + '\r'

        append_result_to_report(result)
```

This works, but as you can see it already, the number of times `for photo in answer.photos.all()` will be executed equal to the number of answers in the db.

Preferably, I would like to only execute two db querys, one fetches all of the answers and the other fetches all of the photos. So I tried this:

```python
def report():
    answers = Answer.objects.all()
    photos = list(Photo.objects.all()) # <- store the result in memory
    for answer in answers:
        result = extract_data(answer)
        for photo in photos: 
            if photo.answer_id = answer.id:
                result += photo.name + '\r'

        append_result_to_report(result)
```

This approach has decreased the number of db queries down to two but it takes even longer to execute as whole. 9.5 seconds for this approach vs 7.5 seconds for the 1st approach.

Any suggestions on how to be more effcient?

Thank you!

P.S. I am using Django 1.8.2

---

UPDATE: I used the method suggested by @Mark Galloway, and the execution time has dropped to 1.6 seconds. The number of queries becomes 3. Django performed the following query:

- select * from answer
- select * from photo
- select * from photo where 'photo.answer_id' in (19,20,3...) # the numbers inside the () does not seem to be continous

I wonder what is the purpose of the last query?

Comment: Is `answer.photos.all()` already a list?

Comment: @Sinux no, it is a queryset.  `photos` is the related_name I defined in the Photo model which allows the Answer model to back reference the photos that belong to a particular Answer model.

Comment: The last query is just django's way of joining models. The id list is computed from the first query. Not sure why you get the second query though, did you forget to remove `photos = list(Photo.objects.all())` ?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger There are other queries running on this page and I thought those are the ones related to this issues. (I hand picked these three out of a list) I could be wrong though.

Comment: I believe this question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), you can walk the one-to-many relationship and fetch all of the photos in two queries. One for all of the answers, and another for all of the photos which are related to the answers.

```
answers = Answer.objects.all().prefetch_related('photos')

for answer in answers:
    result = extract_data(answer)
    for photo in answer.photos.all(): 
        result += photo.name + '\r'

    append_result_to_report(result)
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I did an edit and put `.all()` to the end of `answer.photos` because `answer.photos` is a RelatedManager object instead of a queryset.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) query modifier:

```
def report():
    # fetches answers and photos, both, at once
    answers = Answer.objects.all().select_related('photos')

    for answer in answers:
        result = extract_data(answer)
        for photo in answer.photos.all():
            result += photo.name + '\r'

        append_result_to_report(result)
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the Answer model does not have a foreighkey points to photo. P.S. I didn't do the down vote.

Comment: Always thought prefetch_related was for ManyToManyFields and select_related for anything else. I guess it's prefetch to get a set and select to get a unique related object